# How to use vertical navbar in combination with ui-router to place partials into the main content area

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I would like to split my page into a vertical navbar section (to the left), and a main content area (to the right), and have my partial views, which correspond to different navigation choices, show up in the "main" content area.
So far, my partial view "ResourceDashboard.html" shows up right underneath the navbar, instead of to the right of it.

Here is my vertical navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="resourceDashboard">Resource Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Availability</a></li>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to designate this div below as the main content area, and inject different partial views into this area upon user selection:

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Here is my entire index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="TaskManager">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Task Manager</title>
    <link href="themes/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/default-theme/ej.widgets.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/default-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/responsive-css/ej.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="themes/navbarStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.globalize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jsondata.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jsondata.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ej.widget.angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/properties.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/resourceDashboardController.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="resourceDashboard">Resource Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Availability</a></li>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>



<div ui-view=""></div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my ui-router stuff:

```
angular.module('TaskManager', ['ejangular','ui.router'])

    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('resourceDashboard', {
                url: '/resourceDashboard',
                templateUrl: 'views/ResourceDashboard.html',
                controller: 'ResourceDashboardController'
            })
    });
```

How can I accomplish this two-panel layout

Comment: So that's really only a problem with styling, correct?

Comment: I believe so. Just don't know how to split the page into a left-side vertical nav and a right-side main content

Comment: If you just want a vertical nav for bootstrap, you can search around for examples.  Here's one: http://www.jonathanbriehl.com/2014/01/17/vertical-menu-for-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Thanks tyler! Your example worked.

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg : cool. If you still can, please remove the `angularjs` and `angular-ui-router` tags, as they are not related to the issue.